# PyGears how to send Queue as init for accum

Tags: python, pygears

I have bias for module **my_dot** which is Queue interface. Now, I would like to send this **bias** as **init** for accum but without EOT. How to do this?

```
@gear
def my_dot(din: Queue[Tuple[Fixp[9, 16], Fixp[9, 16]]], bias):
    return din \
        | queuemap(f=mul) \
        | accum(init=din.dtype.data(bias)) \
        | g_qround(fract=7) \
        | g_saturate(t=Fixp[9, 16])
```

Answer (score 1):

You did it rightm the only thing you missed is firght number conversion. Instead using **din.dtype.data** use this:

```
@gear
def my_dot(din: Queue[Tuple[Fixp[9, 16], Fixp[9, 16]]], bias):
    return din \
        | queuemap(f=mul) \
        | accum(init=bias | Fixp[18, 32]) \
        | g_qround(fract=7) \
        | g_saturate(t=Fixp[9, 16])
```

PyGears doesn't have a problem with Queue, framework knows what it should do, so he will drop of EOT and take only "Number".